# ReactJS Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on search filter in reactjs, currently on first or second attempt when user enter the value it working fine but when user enter some text on third attempt it generate the error that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null` . I will provide me logic as a code could some one please help me how to solve this problem . I am new to ReactJS and don't have much knowledge to solve this problem .

**Code**

```
    searchHandler(event) {
    let keyword = event.target.value;
    clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
    this.typingTimer=setTimeout(()=>{
      let filter= {

        "where": {
          "or": [
            {
              "companyName":{"regexp":keyword +"/i"}
            },
            {
              "primaryPhone":{"regexp":keyword +"/i"}
            },
            {
              "emailAddress":{"regexp":keyword +"/i"}
            },
            {
              "venueCode":{"regexp":keyword +"/i"}
            },
            {
              "website":{"regexp":keyword +"/i"}
            },
          ]
        }
      }

      this.props.getParties(filter);
      let filtered = this.state.data.filter(item => {
        return (
          item.companyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 ||
          item.primaryPhone.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 ||
          item.emailAddress.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 ||
          item.venueCode.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 ||
          item.website.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 ||
          item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1
        );
      });

      if (keyword === "") {
        filtered = [];
        this.getData();
      }

      this.setState({
        filtered,
      });
      const { skip } = this.state;
      if(this.state.filtered.length>0 || !this.state.filtered.length){
        this.setState({
          filtered:[],
          skip: skip - skipDecrement
        })
      }
    },550)

  }
```

Comment: means one of the item.XYZ is null

Comment: Yes , I don't know why it appear as null .

Comment: well whatever is setting it is putting null in it....

Comment: Please, do not change the code in your question so that it invalidates answers. Also, do not post duplicate of your question.

Comment: I solve this by added ? after property like item.companyName?.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1

Answer (score 4):

Problem you have is whatever is setting data is setting the properties to null. So when you check it, it throws an error.

You can make your code complicated and check to see if it is truthy before doing it.

```
(item.companyName && item.companyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1) ||
(item.primaryPhone && item.primaryPhone.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1) ||
```

Personally I would not do that and I would use `some` and `includes`.

Define an array of the fields to check

```
const fields = ['companyName','primaryPhone','emailAddress','venueCode','website','description']
```

And in your filter code, use some and loop over and see if they are truthy and is a match

```
let filtered = keyword.length
  ? this.state.data.filter(item =>
      fields.some(prop =>
        item[prop] && item[prop].toLowerCase().includes(keyword)
      )
    )
  : []
```

---

Next issue with your code is this

```
if(this.state.filtered.length>0 || !this.state.filtered.length)
```

The first statement says if greater than zero and second one is is zero. So not sure what you are expecting to happen.

Next issue you have is you are reading this.state.filtered. Problem is you set it right above with `this.setState(....)`. The problem is setState is asynchronous so the value you are checking is not going to be there. You have the variable `filtered` so use it.

```
if (!filtered.length)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case your object values are not set:

```js
(item.companyName||'').toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword)
```

Comment: well error is gone but this expression is not working . could you please check 
if(this.state.filtered.length>0 || !this.state.filtered.length){
        this.setState({
          filtered:[],
          skip: skip - skipDecrement
        })
      }

Comment: sorry , I am not getting you ?

Comment: If you provide me with a more complete snippet of code I may be able to help you out :)

Comment: Can we do teamviewer session for 10 minute ? if possible

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle, you can use a site like https://jsfiddle.net/ and share a link here in you question

Comment: Can't be for certain (as its not in a running state) but if you weren't aware of it `this.setState()` is asynchronous, so that means even though you are setting `filtered` with `setState()` above `if(this.state.filtered.length>0...`, it does not necessarily mean that the value of `this.state.filtered` has been updated yet.*If you need the updated value right away:* use the second parameter of `this.setState({filtered}, updatedState=> {if(updatedState.filtered.length){...}} )`. This should give the the results you are expecting

Comment: Please check out https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3 for an overview

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina or like what was stated in my answer,,,, there is no need to use the callback because they have the value already.... But in reality setState looks to be called too many times, and could be refactored to be called just once.

Comment: I tried but does't work for me , Could you please write it through jsfiddle.net

Comment: As @epascarello stated, you already have the value, there is a better way that this could be written.  I will update my answer shortly so you may see how to write this :)

Comment: You will have to take a further look in when to update your state, it looks like you unecessarily update `filtered` and unset the value afterwards. I do not know what you would like to do with that. But with regards to setting your `filtered` variable, something like this will suffice.. sorry for the formatting:

Comment: let filtered = [];if(keyword!==""){/* Mutation of props/state is taboo in React.You were mutating state here, by doing [...x] you can create a new instance of the array */filtered = [...this.state.data].filter(item => ((item.companyName || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 || (item.primaryPhone || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 || (item.emailAddress || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 || (item.venueCode || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 || (item.website || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1 || (item.description || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > -1));}

Comment: Thats the best I can do without so more questions, I you have some more questions feel free to post a new question :)

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina , Actually , I am unset the filtered values after user do search , if you see `skip: skip - skipDecrement` it update the state but when I try with `skip:0` it not updating my state . If state of `skip:0` is updated correctly it will solve my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191334/discussion-between-miroslav-glamuzina-and-andrew).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add check before calling `toLowerCase` as this is only available on only string

```js
let a  = ''
let b = undefined
let c = [1,2,3]
let d = null
let e = 'HELLO'

typeof a === 'string' && a && console.log(a.toLowerCase())
typeof b === 'string' && b && console.log(b.toLowerCase())
typeof c === 'string' && c && console.log( c.toLowerCase())
typeof d === 'string' && d && console.log( d.toLowerCase())
typeof e === 'string' && e && console.log( e.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: @epascarello added null too, but i hope it's pretty clear from the above examples

Answer (score 0):

means one of the item.XYZ is null ... in the search bar when the view is created it will appear null that's why...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).